# where is org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat, jdbc, derby

I downloaded the jar of [Core Apache Derby database engine, which also includes the embedded JDBC driver (10.9.1.0)](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.derby/derby). But that jar doesn't include the `.class` file of `ClientDriver` in the jdbc package. Why is that ? Where can i find this class file ? I need this file to connect to derby database from tomcat as the server.

Please provide the download link of the complete jar so that i get the required `.class` file.

Comment: Uh, what makes you think we can just magically produce download links? Did you try this thing called "google"? It helps you find things on the web...

Comment: Are you sure you can't use ["org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver"](http://db.apache.org/derby/integrate/DerbyTomcat5512JPetStor.html)?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

OK: have you looked on the Apache Derby page:

- http://db.apache.org/derby/releases/release-10.9.1.0.cgi

Download db-derby-10.9.1.0-bin.zip

It contains many files, including `derby.jar` and `derbyclient.jar` (along with much documentation).

`derbyclient.jar` contains our friend `org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver.class`

Comment: I don't know when, but in the db-derby-10.15.2.0-bin the derbyclient.jar doesn't contains the org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver.class. I found it in the derbytools.jar

Comment: @Gregory: thank you for the update.  The "when" was "Derby 10.15".  Now, in order to use the Derby client driver with Derby 10.15, you need all three of derbyclient.jar, derbyshared.jar, and derbytools.jar.  Sigh... Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57221011/421195) for details.

Answer (score 9):

@Paulsm4 is correct. 
But please keep in mind also that:

> org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver

which can be found inside **derbyclient.jar** is enough to just obtain connection to the **running** Derby DB server.

But if you would like to create embedded (in memory) database when obtaining connection, then you have to use different jdbc driver:

> org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver

which can be found inside **derby.jar**. Moreover, additional parameter `create=true` has to be passed. For example:

```
<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:derby:myApp;databaseName=myApp;create=true" />
```

Hope it helps somebody.