# Class [org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver] not found Exception

Tags: java, tomcat, netbeans, jdbc, javadb

![JAVADB_DRIVER_LABEL library missing][1]

I am trying to connect to a JavaDB through netbeans 8 IDE on Windows 7. i can connect it using the DB manager provided with netbeans in Services panel. But when trying to connect it through my code I get ClassNotFoundException for the org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver class.

I could not run the Apache tomcat server on my machine, so I am Using the Glassfish server 4 that comes with netbeans.

my code to connect to the DB is as follows:

```
String url = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/sample;UID=app;PWD=app";
Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver");
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
```

This similar code worked with SQL server, MS Access.

Answer (score 0):

Please add your jdbc driver to the classpath of your project. It should work.
Currently, the class loader is unable to load your driver class as it does it does not find it in the classpath

Comment: Thanks. I have added the requisite library to the project. see the screen shot at [link] https://www.dropbox.com/s/zjrebxpoh066l4h/Screenshot%202015-04-16%2015.56.31.png?dl=0.

Comment: Cool. Please mark an answer as correct so that it could help others too.

Answer (score 0):

Download the version of Apache Derby you need from [here](https://db.apache.org/derby/derby_downloads.html). Extract the zip and you should get `derbyclient.jar` which has the class `org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver`.

FYI : If your application runs on JDK 1.6 or higher, then you do not need to explicitly load the EmbeddedDriver. In that environment, the driver loads automatically.

Comment: Thank you for reply. I have tried adding the jar files to the library through "Add JAR/Folder". I am new to J2EE and netbeans. So don't know how to add the jar file in classpath.  I am using Netbeans 8 with JDK7, but still not loading.

Comment: I tried the library found at http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/derby/derbyclient/10.11.1.1/derbyclient-10.11.1.1.jar

Added it to the project and it worked.

thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `derbyclient.jar` to your classpath. You can find this jar in the download package of derby from [here](https://db.apache.org/derby/derby_downloads.html). This jar contains your `org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver`.

For more information, see this answer : [where is org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11533921/where-is-org-apache-derby-jdbc-clientdriver)

Comment: Thanks for replying. Done that. no help! see the screen shot at [link]https://www.dropbox.com/s/zjrebxpoh066l4h/Screenshot%202015-04-16%2015.56.31.png?dl=0

Comment: I tried the library found at http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/derby/derbyclient/10.11.1.1/derbyclient-10.11.1.1.jar

Added it to the project and it worked.

thank you all.

Comment: If this answers your question, please mark it as selected answer.