# NetBeans: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver on accessing a JSP page

Tags: java, jsp, derby

I've been looking at a few similar questions but I can't seem to work out a solution for my issue. I'm using NetBeans 11.2, created an ANT Web Project and have successfully created a Derby Database which I'm now trying to access from a JSP. This is the Tomcat log when trying to access the jsp:

```
    10-Dec-2019 13:51:54.773 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-40] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/Einkauf] threw exception [Beim Verarbeiten von [index.jsp] ist in Zeile [20] eine Ausnahme erzeugt worden

    17:         
    18:         <h2>Kunden</h2>
    19:         
    20:         <sql:setDataSource var = "mydata" 
    21:                            driver = "org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver" 
    22:                            url = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/Shop" 
    23:                            user = "nutzer" 


    Stacktrace:] with root cause
        java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver
            at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1365)
            at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1188)
            at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
            at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:416)
            at org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.sql.DataSourceWrapper.setDriverClassName(DataSourceWrapper.java:55)
            at org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.sql.SetDataSourceTagSupport.doStartTag(SetDataSourceTagSupport.java:111)
            at org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspx_meth_sql_005fsetDataSource_005f0(index_jsp.java:216)
            at org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:152)
            at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
            at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
            at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:477)
            at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385)
            at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329)
            at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
            at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
            at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:526)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
            at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
            at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:678)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
            at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
            at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:367)
            at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
            at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:860)
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1591)
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
            at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
            at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
            at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830)
```

I've already added the derbyclient.jar to the libraries, I also copied it into the web-inf\lib directory, still the same error message. This is my index.jsp:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<%@ taglib uri = "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix = "c" %>
<%@ taglib uri = "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql" prefix = "sql" %>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Shopdatenbank</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Shopdatenbank</h1>

        <h2>Kunden</h2>

        <sql:setDataSource var = "mydata" 
                           driver = "org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver" 
                           url = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/Shop" 
                           user = "nutzer" 
                           password = "passwort"
                           scope = "session"/>
        <sql:query var="result" dataSource="${mydata}">
            SELECT * FROM Kunde;
        </sql:query>

        <table border="1" width="100%">
            <tr>
                <th>KID</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Strasse</th>
                <th>PLZ</th>
                <th>Ort</th>
            </tr>
            <c:forEach items="${result.rows}" var="kunden">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <c:out value="${kunden.kid}"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <c:out value="${kunden.name}"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <c:out value="${kunden.strasse}"/>
                    </td>        
                    <td>
                        <c:out value="${kunden.plz}"/>
                    </td>    
                    <td>
                        <c:out value="${kunden.ort}"/>
                    </td>    
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Am I still missing something?

Comment: If you want to connect to a database using jdbc, you will need a driver for that database. That driver needs to be in the classpath of the webapp so that it can be found by the java classloader. It's not there, hence the `ClassNotFoundException`.

Comment: @f1sh so how would I do that? As mentioned in the initial question, I added the derbyclient.jar to the libraries for the project and I even put it into the web-inf/lib directory. Where do I need to put it or declare it for the webapp so that it can be found?

Comment: What version of Derby? If it's 10.15, perhaps you are hitting https://stackoverflow.com/a/57221011/193453

Comment: @BryanPendleton thanks, adding all these jars has at least changed the error message a bit: `javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Unable to get connection, DataSource invalid: "java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/Shop"` I'm a bit puzzled as the derby database is up and running and I now have all the Jars from the other post included.

Comment: Ah, mind you, I had changed the driver to org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver just to check it out and forgot to change it back to ClientDriver. Seems to work now. Thank you all very much!