# How do I fix the issue of ClientDriver not found in Netbeans?

Tags: netbeans, derby, javadb

I have created a JavaDB in Netbeans and succesfully connected to it. But when I try to create a database (by right clicking on JavaDB) I get this issue. How do I fix it ?

[image]

By the way, my driver (Java DB Network) contains the same class that the above window says not found so I don't understand why it isn't working.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/57216394/193453

Comment: Having the same issue. This presumably isn't related to a project dependency but an issue with NetBeans itself since the connection attempt is being made in the Services section. The default drivers aren't pointing to the correct Derby classes (`org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver` & `org.apache.derby.client.ClientAutoloadedDriver`), but even after fixing those this error still persists. It's as if NetBeans is not reading from the Drivers section but using some internal (and incorrect) default instead.